# I'm having trouble installing Odoo in file requirements

Tags: python, odoo-15

I followed all the installation steps from the Odoo Documents
When writing this pip install -r requirements.txt
I hope the experts in Odoo and Python can help me solve this problem
ــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــ

```
     psutil/_psutil_windows.c(272): error C2094: label 'error' was undefined
     I get these problems

      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.31.31103\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for psutil
  Running setup.py clean for psutil
Failed to build psutil
Installing collected packages: psutil, Pillow, MarkupSafe, lxml, libsass, isodate, idna, docutils, defusedxml, decorator, beautifulsoup4, Babel, vobject, requests, reportlab, ofxparse, Jinja2, gevent, freezegun, requests-toolbelt, pyopenssl, ebaysdk, zeep
  Running setup.py install for psutil ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for psutil did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [47 lines of output]
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil
      copying psutil\_common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil
      copying psutil\_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil
      copying psutil\_psaix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil
      copying psutil\_psbsd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil
      copying psutil\_pslinux.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil
      copying psutil\_psosx.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil
      copying psutil\_psposix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil
      copying psutil\_pssunos.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil
      copying psutil\_pswindows.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil
      copying psutil\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
      copying psutil\tests\runner.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
      copying psutil\tests\test_aix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
      copying psutil\tests\test_bsd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
      copying psutil\tests\test_connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
      copying psutil\tests\test_contracts.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
      copying psutil\tests\test_linux.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
      copying psutil\tests\test_memory_leaks.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
      copying psutil\tests\test_misc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
      copying psutil\tests\test_osx.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
      copying psutil\tests\test_posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
      copying psutil\tests\test_process.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
      copying psutil\tests\test_sunos.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
      copying psutil\tests\test_system.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
      copying psutil\tests\test_unicode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
      copying psutil\tests\test_windows.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
      copying psutil\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
      copying psutil\tests\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
      running build_ext
      building 'psutil._psutil_windows' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\psutil
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\psutil\arch
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\psutil\arch\windows
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPSUTIL_VERSION=566 -DPSUTIL_WINDOWS=1 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x01000 -D_AVAIL_WINVER_=0x01000 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DPSAPI_VERSION=1 -Ic:\users\ayobqorban\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\ayobqorban\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt /Tcpsutil/_psutil_common.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\psutil/_psutil_common.obj
      _psutil_common.c
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPSUTIL_VERSION=566 -DPSUTIL_WINDOWS=1 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x01000 -D_AVAIL_WINVER_=0x01000 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DPSAPI_VERSION=1 -Ic:\users\ayobqorban\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\ayobqorban\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt /Tcpsutil/_psutil_windows.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\psutil/_psutil_windows.obj
      _psutil_windows.c
      psutil/_psutil_windows.c(272): error C2094: label 'error' was undefined
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.31.31103\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> psutil

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you created different `environment` for this odoo installation.
Make environment (if not already)
remove `psutil`
Activate environment. install `psutil` `sudo apt-get install -y python-psutil`
Note: All odoo requirements gets trouble installing if OS is different from **UBUNTU**